# pushing object to array of object resulting unexpected change to whole array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

let's jump to the problem

```js
// lets say i have a simple array of objects inside an object

const abc = {
  a: 1,
  b: [{aa: 1, bb: 2}, {aa: 2, bb: 2}]
}

// then I want to update the array with push a new object

abc.b.push({aa: 3, bb: 3})
```

But why it is resulting

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: [[Object], [Object], [Object]]
}
```

I expecting the result

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: [{aa: 1, bb: 2}, {aa: 2, bb: 2}, {aa: 3, bb: 3}]
}
```

The result I got with nodejs `console.log(abc)`

Comment: that is normal, that is console.log problem.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(abc))` is solution

Comment: There is no unexpected change to the array. Just a difference in how the console chooses to display the data.

Comment: Just use `console.debug()` instead

Comment: You can also use `console.debug(abc)` or `console.dir(abc)` to get the result in nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const abc = {
  a: 1,
  b: [{aa: 1, bb: 2}, {aa: 2, bb: 2}]
}

// then I want to update the array with push a new object

abc.b.push({aa: 3, bb: 3})
console.log(JSON.stringify(abc))
```

Comment: You can also use `console.debug(abc)` or `console.dir(abc)`  to get the result in nodejs.